# how to run sequence of command at startup?

Tags: startup

I need to run a sequence of command at the startup.  This sequence require the root password as well. How can I do that?

This is in particular the sequence of command that I need to run:

```
virginia@asus-F552CL:~$ cd MT7630E_Wi-Fi_BT_Source_Release_20140625/rt2x00/
virginia@asus-F552CL:~/MT7630E_Wi-Fi_BT_Source_Release_20140625/rt2x00$ sudo su
[sudo] password for virginia: 
root@asus-F552CL:/home/virginia/MT7630E_Wi-Fi_BT_Source_Release_20140625/rt2x00# ./load.sh
root@asus-F552CL:/home/virginia/MT7630E_Wi-Fi_BT_Source_Release_20140625/rt2x00# exit
virginia@asus-F552CL:~/MT7630E_Wi-Fi_BT_Source_Release_20140625/rt2x00$
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you've mentioned having to do sudo su, I assume that you want these commands to be executed after login.

To do so, you'll have to put your commands in a script file, say, `myCom.sh`. The contents would look like below:

```
cd MT7630E_Wi-Fi_BT_Source_Release_20140625/rt2x00/
echo myPassword | sudo -S su && sudo su -c ./load.sh
```

Note that exit is not required as each command is run as root and script returns back after completion.

Also "myPassword" is to be provided in plain-text.

Then Use KDE/ Ubuntu's startup manager to start this script. Or you could place this file directly in `~/.profile`.

On the other hand, if you want to run these commands on startup rather than login, you could use init scripts. You'll not have to use `sudo su` there as everything will run in root context.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your **/etc/rc.local** file that is executed as last service at run level startup sequence and it grants root permission.

Here is an example:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.
cd /home/virginia/MT7630E_Wi-Fi_BT_Source_Release_20140625/rt2x00
/bin/bash load.sh
exit 0
```

Verify your change with this command:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/rc.local start
```

Please note the following points:

1. load.sh will run as root
2. the environment is restricted, so you may need to define missing variables
3. if you want to log into **syslog**, use `logger "message"`

If is possible I suggest you to execute your script like this:

```
  /bin/bash /home/virginia/MT7630E_Wi-Fi_BT_Source_Release_20140625/rt2x00/load.sh
```

On Ubuntu runlevel start when `filesystem and static-network-up` event occurs. If you need to start **load.sh** at particular event, than is better define [upstart task](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#task).