# Shell scripting,

Tags: command-line, updates, login, scripts, sudo

I made a simple update script. Now My question was is it possible to run it automatically by loggin in on the Ubuntu Desktop and automatically provide my password (`sudo`) for this so I don't have to do anything to keep it updated.

This is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y
```

I would really be helped with this.

Comment: Your commands are in the wrong order. You need to do `sudo apt-get update` first. This will update the package list, which will then be used for the upgrade.

Comment: Changed that now

Answer (score 0):

You can add the script to run at start with:

```
sudo mv /sciptname /etc/init.d/
sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/scriptname
sudo update-rc.d scriptname defaults
```

I would edit the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo apt-get update > /var/log/updatelog
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y >> /var/log/updatelog
```

Then the output goes to the file `/var/log/updatelog`, so you can look there if something is wrong.

**However a better way would to use** `unattended-upgrades`:

```
sudo apt-get install unattended-upgrades
sudo dpkg-reconfigure unattended-upgrades
```

Comment: scripts under SystemV runs as root

Comment: Oh, yes you are right.

Comment: May be more simple use rc.local. Take a look at [how to run sequence of command at startup?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/497699/how-to-run-sequence-of-command-at-startup/497784)

Comment: `unattended-upgrades` is the smimplest way.

Comment: Yes, I agree, I was referring to the first part of your answer, but it does not matter

Comment: I installed the unattended-upgrades. we'll see how it works. :)