# rc.local won't execute the script

Tags: boot, command-line, server, execute-command

This is my rc.local

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

cd /root/server/srv/
./start_srv &

exit 0
```

When I execute

```
    cd /root/server/srv/
    ./start_srv &
```

via terminal myself, it starts normally and everything works
but when I try and do it through rc.local it wont start.

I know rc.local doesn't need sudo etc.
I tried executing rc.local myself through terminal and I get the error: "Can't CD to..."

What am I doing wrong?

ls -ld /root: `drwx------ 4 root root 4096`,

ls -ld /root/server: `drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096`,

ls -ld /root/server/srv/start_srv: `-rwxr-x--x 1 500 500 468420`

ls -ld /root/server/srv: `drwxrwxrwx 2 500 500 4096`

Comment: Please add the output of `ls -ld /root`, `ls -ld /root/server/`, `ls -ld /root/server/srv` and `ls -ld /root/server/srv/start_srv`. Also the complete error when running `/etc/rc.local` by hand could be useful.

Comment: ls -ld /root: drwx------ 4 root root 4096,
ls -ld /root/server: drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096,
ls -ld /root/server/srv/start_srv: -rwxr-x--x 1 500 500 468420

Comment: You forgot `ls -ld /root/server/srv`...

Comment: ls -ld /root/server/srv: drwxrwxrwx 2 500 500 4096

Comment: Strange permissions, but should be ok. What is the exact error when you try to execute `/etc/rc.local/` by hand? With which user you do that? Which user is the one with UID=500 which seems not to be recognized by the system? ---- and please, add the info on the question, it is almost unreadable in the comments.

Comment: `cd` is not an executable, but a command for the shell. I am not sure, but maybe you can't run it via `rc.local`. Why don't you just call `/root/server/srv/start_srv &` instead?

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto, `cd` works perfectly in scripts. And maybe the script need to be started with the current directory set. I would really do a `(cd ... && ./start_script ) &` to use a subshell and not change the CWD globally, but this is nitpicking...

Comment: It says: "Can't CD to /root/server/srv/"

Comment: any ideas? anyone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to verify your `/etc/rc.local` script you should use this command:

```
  sudo service rc.local start
```

When system `init` starts `rc.local` scripts it runs as **root**, but if you want to check your script, you need to become **root** via `sudo` command.

That is why you got errors like `Can't CD to /root/server/srv/`.

If your script doesn't work during startup process, consider that the environment is restricted, so you should define missing variables as your script needs.

[Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/497699/how-to-run-sequence-of-command-at-startup/497784#497784) is an example.

The error:  `/bin/sh: 0: Illegal option -` is due to `DOS` file format.

In order to fix it you should install [**dos2unix**](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/dos2unix) utility and convert rc.local file:

```
  sudo dos2unix /etc/rc.local
```

Comment: Hello I am getting: 
'/bin/sh: 0: Illegal option -'
when I try to 'sudo /etc/rc.local start'

Comment: In order to exec /etc/rc.local you should use 'sudo /etc/init.d/rc.local start' not 'sudo /etc/rc.local start'.

Comment: Okay. I tried both but I still got the same message. '/bin/sh: 0: Illegal option -'

Comment: Sorry, check first line of rc.local. is it exactly '#!/bin/sh -e'? An other question: is your script 'start_srv' an 'sh' script?

Comment: First line is: '#!/bin/sh -e' exactly copied from rc.local. start_srv is not an 'sh' script. Its just a script to run a voip server made for linux.

Comment: it's really weird, it seems that sh is not sh :) Could you post 'ls -l /bin/sh' output?

Comment: ls -l /bin/sh: 'lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Jul 30 22:54 /bin/sh -> dash'

Comment: It is ok, so it seems that dash doesn't recognize '-e' option. Did you edit rc.local from windows? Could you post your ubuntu release? Could you remove -e options and post 'sudo /etc/init.d/rc.local start' output?

Comment: Yes, I did edit the rc.local from Windows. I thought that wouldn't make any problems. I'm new to Ubuntu. Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS.

Comment: I updated my answer, windows use DOS format that doesn't work on ubuntu.

Comment: I changed few lines with 'sudo vi /etc/rc.local' editor, saved and exited. I double checked that the new changes have been saved. But I am still getting :'/bin/sh: 0: Illegal option -'.

Comment: Sorry I was wrong, I thought that 'gedit' would change file format. I updated my answer.

Comment: Its working now, thanks for all the help! I know my problems are a little bit "specific" because of my lack of knowledge :)